# Wordpress freezes when trying to update woocommerce order status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

It's been a week since I'm experiencing a bug in woocommerce,
whole site is good except for the order status change.

When I try to change the status (example: Waiting Payment to Completed) it takes 5 minutes to do it, and the website is not available in those 5 minutes.

In the debog log I got the following (the italian text is: status was incorrectly recalled):

> [11-Apr-2020 20:52:25 UTC] PHP Notice:  status è stato richiamato
>   **in maniera scorretta**. Order properties should not be
>   accessed directly. Backtrace: edit_post, wp_update_post,
>   wp_insert_post, do_action('save_post'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Admin_Meta_Boxes->save_meta_boxes,
>   do_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data::save, WC_Order->save,
>   WC_Order->status_transition,
>   do_action('woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_processing'),
>   WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
>   WC_Emails::send_transactional_email,
>   do_action_ref_array('woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_processing_notification'),
>   WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
>   WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order->trigger, WC_Email->get_content,
>   WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order->get_content_html,
>   wc_get_template_html, wc_get_template,
>   include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-processing-order.php'),
>   do_action('woocommerce_email_order_details'), WP_Hook->do_action in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line
>   5167

The line 5167 is the debug message itself (**E_USER_NOTICE** is the line 5167):

```
            trigger_error(
            sprintf(
                /* translators: Developer debugging message. 1: PHP function name, 2: Explanatory message, 3: Version information message. */
                __( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s' ),
                $function,
                $message,
                $version
            ),
            E_USER_NOTICE
        );
    } else {
        if ( is_null( $version ) ) {
            $version = '';
        } else {
            $version = sprintf( '(This message was added in version %s.)', $version );
        }

        $message .= sprintf(
            ' Please see <a href="%s">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.',
            'https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/'
        );
```

I updated wordpress core but nothing changes
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Solved updating woocommerce to lastest version,
thank you